# Can you combine ECC and Non-ECC RAM in the same system (Mid 2012 Mac Pro)? Obviously the DDR number is the same, as is the speed (DDR3 1066MHz)

Tags: mac, memory

I have 2 Mac Pros that I need to be at 4GB RAM each, one currently has 6GB with 3x 2GB 1066MHz DDR3 ECC and the other has 3GB with 3x 1GB 1066MHz DDR3.

I know in an ideal world you shouldn't mix sizes and they should all be equal specs but will this be workable and reliable?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to mix sizes. You can put 2x2GB in each. In one case, you have to make the 2GB with 2x1GB, but that's not mixing sizes either.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you should be able to mix ECC and Non-ECC DIMMs, and you should be able to mix DIMM sizes...Unless Apple took extra steps to prevent that from working.